# Memoize a single argument in Python method

Tags: python, numpy, recursion, memoization

I've written a Numpy implementation that uses the Cox-de Boor recursive algorithm to compute B-spline basis functions.  I would like to `memoize` the object instance for a given `order`, but leave the function callable with respect to `xi`.

In other words, after the object is instantiated, the recursive function should be "set", but remain callable at `xi`.  I really need this for speed, as I will be calling the function many times and do not want to reconstruct the recursive function over-and-over.

Here is the current implementation:

```
import numpy as np

#Turn off divide by zero warning because we explicitly check for it
np.seterr(divide='ignore')

class Bspline():

    def __init__(self, knot_vector, order):

        self.knot_vector = knot_vector
        self.p = order


    def __basis0(self, xi):

        return np.where(np.all([self.knot_vector[:-1] <=  xi, 
                            xi < self.knot_vector[1:]],axis=0), 1.0, 0.0)

    def __basis(self, xi, p):

        if p == 0:
            return self.__basis0(xi)
        else:
            basis_p_minus_1 = self.__basis(xi, p - 1)

            first_term_numerator = xi - self.knot_vector[:-p] 
            first_term_denominator = self.knot_vector[p:] - self.knot_vector[:-p]

            second_term_numerator = self.knot_vector[(p + 1):] - xi
            second_term_denominator = self.knot_vector[(p + 1):] - self.knot_vector[1:-p]

            first_term = np.where(first_term_denominator > 1.0e-12, 
                              first_term_numerator / first_term_denominator, 0)
            second_term = np.where(second_term_denominator > 1.0e-12,
                               second_term_numerator / second_term_denominator, 0)

            return  first_term[:-1] * basis_p_minus_1[:-1] + second_term * basis_p_minus_1[1:]


    def __call__(self, xi):

        return self.__basis(xi, self.p)
```

and is used as

```
knot_vector = np.array([0,0,0,0,0,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5])
basis = Bspline(knot_vector,4)
basis(1.2)
```

which returns the basis functions evaluated at `1.2`.  However, I need to call this function many times and as it is written now, the recursive function is reconstructed for every call, and this is not necessary as the recursion level is set at instantiation as `4`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's very easy to memoize anything using [`functools.lru_cache`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache) in Python3, or, in Python2.7 using something like [this](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577452-a-memoize-decorator-for-instance-methods/):

```
class Bspline(object):
    ...

    # Python2.7
    @memoize
    # or, Python3*
    @functools.lru_cache()
    def op(self, args):
        return self._internal_op(xi)
```

Comment: I like this solution, but is it possible to use this inside the class definition?  I am trying to create a clean API, where this memoziation will be done automatically.

Comment: Updated; also for Python2.7.

Comment: Thanks! Used the linked `memoize` function for Python 2.7

Answer (score 0):

Create a dictionary that saves the results of the function and then check to see if that value is in the dict before calling the function again. Something similar to this should work depending on your setup.

```
results = {}
for value in values:
    if results.get(value):
        answer = results[value]
    else:
        answer = basis(value)
        results[value] = answer
        print(answer)  # or just display the results dict once you are done
```